# Modal to edit a field in a Query screen (React Native Expo)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, apk

Each field has two icons, the one to delete and the one to edit, but the one to edit doesn't work when I try to put a function on it and create a modal for it, my question is how should the modal be created to act on the firebase database?

```
    
        return (
          <View key={index} style={styles.item}>
            <Text style={[styles.nombre, { marginRight: 5 }]}>{empleado.nombre}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.empleadoId}>Empleado ID: {empleadoId}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.correo}>Correo: {empleado.correo}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.telefono}>Teléfono: {empleado.telefono}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.cargo}>Cargo: {empleado.cargo}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.direccion}>Dirección: {empleado.direccion}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.sueldo}>Sueldo: {empleado.sueldo}</Text>
            
            
            <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleDelete(empleado.id)}                style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: 'red' }]}>
                <Icon name="trash" size={20} color="white" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleEdit(cliente.idCliente)} style={styles.buttonSmall}>
                <Icon name="edit" size={20} color="#fff" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

I want the correct way to place a modal that allows editing the database, because when I tried it it said render error or something like that.

Comment: Check your import statement for TouchableOpacity.